# Align divs at the bottom right above each other

Tags: css, flexbox

How I can align bottom many divs, one on another. Like on a picture below.

[image]

Comment: Have You tried using aboslute/relative positioning? Another way is big DIV in upper part, then set float:right for Your minor divs.

Comment: I have tried absolute positioning but divs are overlaps in the bottom. I need to set them one on the another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` to do this

1. Set `flex-direction: column` to position divs one on top of another
2. `align-items: flex-end` to move divs to right side of parent
3. `justify-content: flex-end` to move divs to bottom of parent.

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;

}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Update: To reverse order of divs you can use `flex-direction: column-reverse` and `justify-content: flex-start`

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-start;

}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i want!

Comment: but that puts the items in the opposite order than indicated in the question (see my answer for the reversed order, like in the question)

Comment: Didn't notice that, if OP wants reversed order you can just change to `column-reverse` and `justify-content: flex-start` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1626/

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox with flex-direction: `column-reverse;` and `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`:

```css
.x {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-basis: 0%;
  }
  .y {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 3px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div class="y">1</div>
  <div class="y">2</div>
  <div class="y">3</div>
  <div class="y">4</div>
  <div class="y">5</div>
</div>
```